# Plotting points on a line, between points in array

Tags: php, math, plot, coordinate-systems

I'm sure this is a simple one, but my brain is refusing to work right now... I have an array of points, that looks something like:

```
$points = [
    ["x" => 12, "z" => 23],
    ["x" => 42, "z" => 64] etc...
]
```

Now, i need to draw lets say "a dotted line" between all the point, basically making a square, or a closed path, containing only 90 degree turns. I came up with this code:

```
$x = 0;
$y = $this->getYCord(); 
$z = 0;

for($pi = 1; $pi >= count($points); $pi++){
    for($x = $points[$pi - 1]["x"]; $x <= $points[$pi]["x"]; $x += 0.5){
        $this->addDot(new Dot($x, $y, $z));
    }
    for($z = $points[$pi - 1]["z"]; $z <= $points[$pi]["z"]; $z += 0.5){
        $this->addDot(new Dot($x, $y, $z));
    }
}
```

But as you may see, this will encounter a lot or errors, On is: what if the second point has smaller coordinates? then we need to `-=` in the loop. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Possible approach:

```
$left = min($points[$pi]["x"], $points[$pi - 1]["x"]);
$right = max($points[$pi]["x"], $points[$pi - 1]["x"]);
for($x = $left; $x <= $right; $x += 0.5) ...
```